# Change CSS RGBA color based on main template color in SASS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am writing HTML template with SASS.

What I want to achieve is whenever my client change the main template color, the box-shadow color will also be changed and match with the template color.

---

I have a **main template color** variable and **box shadow mixin**.

```
$template-color: #6c8ce2;
```

Box shadow color

```
@mixin box-shadow($amount,$blur,$spread,$opacity) {
  box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba(49, 2, 190, $opacity);
  -webkit-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba(49, 2, 190, $opacity);
  -moz-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba(49, 2, 190, $opacity);
}
```

Here, as **rgba** color code is different with the main template color.This will not work. So I try to achieve it with two options as below.

---

**Method One**
I try to replace **rgba** color with **$template-color** something like this

```
box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread $template-color;
```

But the problem is the box shadow's opacity need to be very soft and transparent.

[Example box shadow image is here](https://ibb.co/cbk7r8)

I can't achieve it without using RGBA's opacity.

---

**Method two**
I also try adding **an alpha hex** behind **$template-color** like this.

```
box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread $template-color+2b
```

The method two problem is every color has its' own alpha hex. It's dynamic and I can't guess it.

Can I achieve it without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your mixin like this to genarate the RGBA from your `$template-color`:

```
@mixin box-shadow($amount, $blur, $spread, $opacity, $template-color) {
  $red: red($template-color);
  $blue: blue($template-color);
  $green: green($template-color);
  box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($red, $green, $blue, $opacity);
  -webkit-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($red, $green, $blue, $opacity);
  -moz-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($red, $green, $blue, $opacity);
}
```

#### Update:

I have found that the `rgba` function accepts two patameters (color and opacity) and you can do this simpler:

```
@mixin box-shadow($amount, $blur, $spread, $opacity, $template-color) 
{
  box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($template-color, $opacity);
  -webkit-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($template-color, $opacity);
  -moz-box-shadow: $amount $blur $spread rgba($template-color, $opacity);
}
```

Comment: uh, This is like a hack, I don't even know this exists. Thank you so much @Mahdi.

Comment: I have searched and found out that you don't even need this hack! the `rgba` function accepts two parameters and can combine a color with an opacity. I will Update my answer.

Comment: I should have tried RGBA with two parameters :D. The update one is better. Thanks again.